# How can I speed up the dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, 13.10

I have this issue with Ubuntu 13.10. The dash is simply too laggy when it comes to type something into it moreover it takes more than 3 secs to open so I can type something inside. It's FASTIDIOUS and quite disappointing. I've seen this issue in computers with much more power resources and that somewhat comply with the standard requirements. Come one I've seen this bug on pc's with 3gb of RAM and 2,6Ghz processors not to mention the advanced graphic cards. Can this bug be solved in the future or will it stick around with Ubuntu as long as it's installed on my pc? Please answer something.

Comment: What kind of pc do you have?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with your hardware and graphics drivers rather than Ubuntu and Unity. The dash is faster than it was with Ubuntu 13.04 or prior releases. If you're using open source drivers, you'll want to immediately add the oibaf PPA to get better open source drivers for your graphics card. However, since oibaf currently does not support Saucy, you'll need to edit oibaf to use raring repos instead.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers; sudo sed -i 's/saucy/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf*; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Then reboot.

If you are using proprietary drivers you will need to uninstall them first. If you are using NVDIA you need to use the closed source drivers from NVIDIA instead with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current -y`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care to have a fancy dash and you just want it to work, I would recommend getting lubuntu.  It is a lot less fancy and much faster.  Just put

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

into terminal.  You can always get back to the default by the login screen.