# How to speed up search for locally installed applications in Ubuntu 13.10's Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I upgraded to **Ubuntu 13.10** *"Saucy Salamander"*. After upgrading, whenever I open the Unity Dash to search for an application, it takes at least a minute before it starts to show some result. The new scopes addition has made Dash painfully slow. Is it possible to speed up the Dash's response time?
I have already turned off the *"include online search results"* option.
I can live without internet information on Dash, but cannot stand a slow application menu (which is supposed to be its primary feature)

Comment: 2 workarounds until Canonical decides to first search our PATH... 1) dock your apps and use Win + 1-9. 2) `sudo apt-get install guake` and `function noh { nohup $@ >/dev/null & }`. Then hit F12 to open guake and `noh firefox` to start Firefox

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can disable individual scopes in the **Dash Plugins** section of Applications Lens. Ubuntu 13.10 brought the **Smart Scopes** feature with lots of feature packed scopes. This may make Unity slow and resource hungry. But it brought a good thing too: you can now selectively disable individual Scopes from the Dash itself.

[image: Unity Dash Plugins Section]
[image: Disable Individual Scopes from Unity Dash]

Previously, scopes could be disabled only by unchecking the corresponding schema entries using `dconf` or `gsettings`. This is not needed now as it can be done from Dash itself. As a more aggressive measure, you can uninstall the unwanted Scopes and Lens. These are packages named like *unity-scope-* or *unity-lens-*. For example, I usually remove *unity-scope-musicstores* and **unity-scope-video-remote* scopes and *unity-lens-music* and *unity-lens-video*. You may remove scopes and lens which use online search or the ones you don't need.

As suggested by [Sushantp606](https://askubuntu.com/users/192102/sushantp606) in [this Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382055/how-to-speed-up-dash-in-ubuntu-13-10/382076#382076) you may disable *Online Searches* in Unity Dash. To do so, goto *System Settings ▸ Privacy ▸ Search Results ▸ When searching in the Dash: Include online search results* and turn it off.
[image: Disable Online Search for Unity Dash]

Turning off *Record Activity* will affect all searches, both online and offline. Don't turn it off, unless you don't mind Dash not displaying recently used Apps, Files, Music, etc.

If you're experiencing slowness during the first search on Dash after startup, it's the **startup delay** of Dash. It'll speed up after a while. The second or subsequent searches will be fast. You may use **preload** or similar daemons to decrease startup delay.

*Disabling Blur* or changing to *Static Blur* can increase Dash performance,but won't do anything in particular to increase Search efficiency. For suggestions to improve Unity Dash performance on the whole,and not just with respect to *Online Searches* refer to [How to speed up the Dash response?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153831/how-to-speed-up-the-dash-response) and [How can I speed up the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362299/how-can-i-speed-up-the-dash-please-answer)

Comment: The problem is its never fast.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not fast? The **Unity Dash** itself isn't fast or the **Search** isn't fast? If it's the search feature, then change the Question Title and avoid being flagged as duplicate of [How can I speed up the dash? Please answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362299/how-can-i-speed-up-the-dash-please-answer)

Comment: Great detailed answer! For me deleting most of the scopes sped up the search a lot (from taking several seconds when typing "Text Editor" to almost instantaneously)! Even though I previously already had turned off the online search results (that brought almost no speedup).

Comment: I can confirm that disabling ~75% of dash plugins (unused anyways) made it instant.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, also go under "Files & Applications" and turn "Record file application usage off" and "Clear Usage Data". That made search instant for me!

Comment: To remove a plugin, go to the applications tab, **scroll down**, and you'll see "Dash plugins." Click one one, and click disable.

Answer (score 1):

Install compiz settings manager :

By running the following in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Now open compiz settings manager and then goto the unity plug-in.
Now disable blur in dash this will increase the speed of your dash significantly.

Comment: wasn't blur a part of Ubuntu 13.04? how did it not affect 13.04?

Comment: No effect can take a minure to display. It's the search that is very slow, the question was abou the search.

Answer (score 1):

open up synaptic and remove the various useless unity-scope-***** and unity-lens-***** applications.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I know is go to System setting - privacy -off include online search, and off record activity, that’s it.

And check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/362313/192102) once that might be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in 13.10, but when I want to search for applications in 14.10, I've gotten in to the habit of using Super+A (for the Application Lens) and not just Super, which searches all Lenses. At least for me, the difference in speed is quite dramatic, even with all the unnecessary lenses already disabled, as suggesting in the accepted answer.